# Xtext - scoping in different files

Tags: xtext

I'm not quite sure I understand how the scoping process works in xText, working with several model files.
Referencing within one file works fine, just having to specify a rule along the lines of `ref=[referencedObject | ID]`, I can get the auto completion to work out of the box ; however, I can't seem to access any `EObject` in another file. The information I found is not very explicit about that case, and I don't really understand what I am supposed to do to make it work...

I tried referencing by `QualifiedName`, but I simply don't get where I'm supposed to make the reference actually happen - how my separate files can access each other.

EDIT : code

```
File returns File:
    UIRule | EventRule
;

QualifiedName:
    ID ('.' ID)*
;

/* First file */
UIRule returns Ui:
    {Ui}
    "ui"
    (screens+=ScreenRule (screens+=ScreenRule)*)?
;

ScreenRule returns Screen:
    name=ID "as" "screen"
    '{'
        (elements+=GUIElementRule )*
    '}'
;
GUIElementRule returns Button:
    name=ID "as" "element"
;


/* Second file */
EventRule returns Event:
    {Event}
    "event"
    rules+=RuleRule*
;

RuleRule returns Rule:
    "on" "{" on=ButtonPressRule "}"
    "do" "{" do=ActionRule "}"
;

ButtonPressRule returns Pressed:
    "press" "[" source=[GUIElement | QualifiedName] "]"
;
ActionRule returns Open:
    "open" "[" screen=[Screen | QualifiedName] "]"
;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between linking within one file and linking between different files: In both cases the link destination is lookup up in the index. So usually there is no distinction between these two cases. BTW, the relevant sections in the manual are [Linking](https://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/303_runtime_concepts.html#linking) and (especially) [Scoping](https://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/303_runtime_concepts.html#scoping).

> I tried referencing by `QualifiedName`, but I simply don't get where I'm supposed to make the reference actually happen - how my separate files can access each other.

The relevant sections of your grammar should look like this (Please note the caps in `ReferencedObject`):

```
ReferencedObject:
    name=ID /* more stuff */;

Something:
    name=ID ref=[ReferencedObject | QN];

QN: 
    ID ('.' ID)*;
```

As long as `ReferencesObject` has a `name` and each of its containers also has a `name` attribut you should be done. I'm assuming that you did not modify the `ScopeProvider` class of your language.

---

EDIT:

The given grammar is not correct and not self contained.

- The first rule **cannot** be a datatype rule like `QualifiedName`. The grammar would not compile with this.
- `NavigationRule` is not used and `ActionRule` is unknown. I assume that for the sake of example `ActionRule` can be replaced with `NavigationRule`.
- The complete `EventRule` part is not used. So either the top-level rule is missing (see first point) **OR** the grammar simply would not know how to parse a file with Event-Rules. Of course scoping and crossreferencing in an unparsable file is difficult ;-)

So: After fixing The `NavigationRule` / `ActionRule` and using the following rule as the first rule I can generate the plugins with not more modification using the standard "MyDsl" example from Xtext:

```
File:
    ui = UIRule | event = EventRule
;
```

Then I can start the editor and write these two files (with code-completion and correct proposals in file 2):

File 1:

```
S1 as screen { 
    S1E1 as element 
    S1E2 as element
}

S2 as screen { 
    S2E1 as element
    S2E2 as element
}
```

File 2:

```
on { press [ S1.S1E1 ] }
do { open [ S2 ] }
```

In the second file the crossreferences are resolved: I can shift-click on `S2` and on `S1.S1E1` and Xtext jumps to the definition.

So if this does not work for you then you should start with a clean project **OR** provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) Example which demonstrates your problem properly.

Comment: This is what I have already done, but I must have made a mistake somewere the references just won't work. "Couldn't resolve reference to ..." error, on and on. 

The object I want to refer to has the `name` A, it is contained inside object B, itself inside object C (root of the file). Is the `QualifiedName` `C.B.A` ? Does the root object need to be named ?

The `ScopeProvider` has not been modified.

Comment: @S.W. First: I fixed the grammar regarding `QN`. Second: The QualifiedName of your example would be `C.B.A`. Without modifying the ScopeProvider you have to use this name for the reference. You don't need to name the root object. Besides of this: it is quite impossible to diagnose the problem without some more _code_. Descriptions in natural language will not work. See http://sscce.org/ for details.

Comment: I added a code sample. Neither of the references from the second file work.

Comment: Indeed, the presented sample contained a lot of mistakes, due to simplification for presentation... (the complete code is much longer, I only presented relevant sections here). I should have proofread, my mistake. Thanks for the insight, this was very helpful anyway :)

Comment: I corrected the code. However, I tried with a clean Xtext project, putting into it only the code I put here - the grammar compiles with no problem, I tried the file examples above, but the references are still unresolved. .... I just can't begin to understand where I got it wrong.

Comment: @S.W. Funny thing is: Your corrected grammar won't compile without substituting `GUIElement` with `Button`. So there's something fishy about your clean project setup. On my side there is only one thing left: Do you use a recent version of Xtext? Scoping did not change significantly in the last releases, but who knows... Besides of this: you can set a breakpoint on `AbstractDeclarativeScopeProvider.getScope` and look where a "Ctrl-Space" before a reference leads you.